# Selecting correct IVY dependency

Tags: ant, ivy

I have a project that makes use of some third-party libraries. Some of these drag in transitive dependencies that have actually several artifacts in the repository:

- module-1.2.jar
- module-1.2-sources.jar
- module-1.2-tests.jar

My investigations tought me that these seem to be Maven build artifacts that where propagated with a classifier. Now it seems that IVY is well able to handle the sources file but when I declare a dependency like this, it appears that the wrong jar is selected:

```
<dependency org="acme" module="module" rev="1.2"/>
```

When I do a resolve in ANT like this

```
<ivy:resolve conf="${ivy.non.test.confs}" validate="false" refresh="true" />
<ivy:retrieve conf="${ivy.non.test.confs}" pattern="${build.lib}/[conf]/[artifact].[ext]" sync="true" />
```

it happens that the module-1.2-tests.jar is selected as resolve target and retrieved under the name of the actual jar name (module-1.2.jar in this example).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you please say which library is it exactly, or posts it's ivy.xml?

Comment: @cantSleepNow it appears that this is related to a known issue in IVY [(IVY-1586)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-1586). For me clearing the IVY cache before each build did the trick.